Breakpoint on a new window being opened
Is it possible to set a breakpoint on all locations that open a new window, like all window.open() calls?
I understand it's possible to use "find in all files" to look for interesting function calls, but for such generic function names (open()) it's tedious or, if the debugged application is large enough, barely viable.
